# Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409) error not opening a website

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qwebengineview

I am creating a desktop app using PyQt5 and QtDesginer. I have a login page connected to a database, and the user is asked to enter username and password. In the designer, I created a window that opens a certain link. The following code is running. But when inserting it into the second code it gives Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409).

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
import sys


class UI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi("website.ui", self)

        self.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = UI()
app.exec_()
```

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import mysql.connector as mc
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog


class Ui_Form(object):

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(500, 193)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.lineEditEmail = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEditEmail.setObjectName("lineEditEmail")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEditEmail)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.lineEditPassword = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEditPassword.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.lineEditPassword.setObjectName("lineEditPassword")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEditPassword)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40,
                                           QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        # this is the signal that we have already connected
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.login)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.labelResult = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.labelResult.setFont(font)
        self.labelResult.setText("")
        self.labelResult.setObjectName("labelResult")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.labelResult)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def login(self):
        try:
            email = self.lineEditEmail.text()
            password = self.lineEditPassword.text()

            mydb = mc.connect(
                host="localhost",
                user="root",
                password="",
                database="program"

            )

            mycursor = mydb.cursor()
            query = "SELECT username,password from user where username " \
                    "like '" + email + "'and password like '" \
                    + password + "'"
            mycursor.execute(query)
            result = mycursor.fetchone()

            if result == None:
                self.labelResult.setText("Incorrect email or password")

            else:
                self.labelResult.setText("You are logged in")
                import Load_exam



        except mc.Error as e:
            self.labelResult.setText("Error")

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Email:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Password:"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Login"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: When does that error occur? What does `Load_exam` do?

Comment: Load exam is the first code: from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
import sys


class UI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi("website.ui", self)

        self.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = UI()
app.exec_()

Comment: The error occurs after logging in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the problem mostly resides in the fact that only *one* and *unique* QApplication instance should ever exist for each process.

When you import `Load_exam` a QApplication instance already exists and is being executed, and that scipt will try to execute the last three lines (since there's no `if __name__ == '__main__'` check), hence the crash.

Before providing the solution, consider the following two aspects:

- import statements should always happen in the beginning of the scripts, as importing within the code (especially within a function) is usually unnecessary and often leads to unexpected problems; for common uses, the only accepted exception is to do that in the `__name__` check;
- editing of files generated by `pyuic` is considered *bad* practice and should never, *ever* be done unless you really know what you're doing (and if you *do* know, you will probably not do it); those files are inteded to be exclusively imported, as explained in the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html);

With the above points in mind, recreate the ui for `Ui_Form` with pyuic (the following assumes the generated file is named `loginForm.py`), and create a new script like this:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from loginForm import Ui_Form
import mysql.connector as mc


class BrowserWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi("website.ui", self)


class LoginWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.login)

    def login(self):
        try:
            email = self.lineEditEmail.text()
            password = self.lineEditPassword.text()

            mydb = mc.connect(
                host="localhost",
                user="root",
                password="",
                database="program"

            )

            mycursor = mydb.cursor()
            query = "SELECT username,password from user where username " \
                    "like '" + email + "'and password like '" \
                    + password + "'"
            mycursor.execute(query)
            result = mycursor.fetchone()

            if result == None:
                self.labelResult.setText("Incorrect email or password")

            else:
                self.labelResult.setText("You are logged in")
                self.showBrowser()

        except mc.Error as e:
            self.labelResult.setText("Error")

    def showBrowser(self):
        self.browser = BrowserWindow()
        self.browser.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    loginWindow = LoginWindow()
    loginWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Since you're already using `uic` for the browser window, you can just skip the `pyuic` part, and just use the same on the login window as well:

```
class LoginWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('loginForm.ui', self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.login)

    # ...
```

Comment: I'm sorry I never heard of pyuic and I just started learning PyQt. So, I created the LoginWindow class, but concerning loading the LoginForm from design, should'nt I look for push button; for example: button = `self.findChild(QPushButton, 'pushButton') `. Ans same thing goes for lineEditEmail and lineEditPassword. Please I need your help.

Comment: I want to point at something else, in my initial code instead of opening a browser, I just put a push button, and the window opened without any error, if O try to open the browser if gives an error

Comment: @Midoz The code you posted with the `Ui_Form` has been created with pyuic. "should'nt I look for push button": have you tried my code? No, you don't need to use `self.findChild` (as lots of tutorials unfortunately suggest, and they are *wrong*): using `uic.loadUi` or the inheritance with `setupUi()` approach results in creating all instance attributes for each widget exactly as they are listed in designer.

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I've resolved in way I'm showing below:
In your code you should change the lower part as follows
`
...
# Change this:
def showBrowser(self):
browser.show()

if **name** == '**main**':
import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

```
# Add this
browser = BrowserWindow()
#
loginWindow = LoginWindow()
loginWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())`
```